# Javax validation constraints not recognized by hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 1.5 with Hibernate 5.2, my problem is that the javax constraints annotations like `@NotNull` are not translated to the database.

```
@Entity
public class Date extends AbstractModel {

    @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
    protected String startDate;

    @NotNull
        @NotEmpty
    protected String endDate;

  // Getters and setters are omitted for brevity
}
```

This code gives no constraints on my MySQL database. I know I can use `@column(nullable=false)`, but how comes that the javax annotations doesn't work?

Comment: Java beans validations like NotNull, NotEmpty affects only objects fields. Validator checking fields and throw exceptions when requirements are not met. You can use these annotations anywhere not only for entity.

Comment: I think that the Java beans validation affects the database too by creating the right constraints when creating the schema. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Oh, you are right. NotNull, NotEmpty and NotBlank should create not null constraints. When do you put these annotations? When table exists these annotations does not runs 'alter table(...)'

Comment: I create the schema with hibernate, so the annotations are set from the beginning